# jQuery form login check without redirect, password and login returns blank

Tags: jquery

I have got a login form that works great without any problems after I submit it to a PHP document. But I don't want it to redirect to a PHP document, so I am trying to do this:

```
<form id="login" name="login" class="col-1 login" action="blocks/loggedIn.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="loginEmail" id="loginEmail" placeholder="email :" class="inputLogin"><br>
    <input type="password" name="loginPassword" id="loginPassword" placeholder="Password :" class="inputLogin"><br>
    <input type="submit" id="loginSubmit" class="button" value="OK"><br>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var lE = document.forms["login"]["loginEmail"].value;
        var lP = document.forms["login"]["loginPassword"].value;
        $('#loginSubmit').click(function(){
            if(lE == null || lE == "" || lP == null || lP == ""){
                alert('Login and password requiret!');
            }else{
                $.post(
                    $('#login').attr('action'),
                    $('#login : input').serializeArray(),
                    function(data){
                        alert(data);
                    }
                );
            };
            $('#login').submit(function(){
                return false;
            });
        });
    }); 
</script>`
```

For some reason variables   `lE`   and   `lP`   returns blank after I submit form.
I have also tried to define them using this :
`var lE = $('#loginEmail').val(); var lP = $('#loginPassword').val();`
But still nothing...  any ideas what this can be?

Comment: Uh, you need to get their values when you submit, not before.  Otherwise they won't be set yet.  You can get their dom references before hand, just get their .value or val() when the submit happens.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing this when the page loads:

```
var lE = document.forms["login"]["loginEmail"].value;
var lP = document.forms["login"]["loginPassword"].value;
```

Unless the user is *really fast* (as in, faster than the computer), no values will have been typed there yet.  So those variables will be empty (or will contain whatever default values you may have in those fields).

Instead, get the values when the form is submitted:

```
$('#loginSubmit').click(function(){
    var lE = document.forms["login"]["loginEmail"].value;
    var lP = document.forms["login"]["loginPassword"].value;
    //...
```